# boost::locale to_utf function for string encoding, likes to throw

Tags: c++, string, locale, boost-locale

I'm having trouble using boost to convert between different string encoding.
[After reading this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html), I tried doing this:

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen.generate("");// encoding local to the computer.
//std::locale loc = gen.generate("en_US.UTF-8"); // tried this too
//std::locale loc = gen.generate("en_US.UTF-8"); //doesn't work either
std::string someString = "test me";
std::string output = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(someString, loc);
```

But it always fails with a std::bad_cast when it tries use_facet() inside to_utf.

This would suggest that the boost locale::info [facet isn't available](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/use_facet/) for the locale being generated. But I tried a few different generations with no luck, and I expect the system default to always work, so I must be doing something wrong else where.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
std::locale loc("");
std::locale conv_loc = boost::locale::util::create_info(loc, loc.name());
std::string output = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(someString, conv_loc);
```